# Google Map add marker using place ID

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-map-place

I am trying to place a marker into Google Maps using its PlaceID. I have the map working and displaying and can also add markers (using Lattitude and Longitude) into it.

> The code below is what I am using to try and make the marker display
>   using its placeID however it is not displaying.

```
function addPlaces(){
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        place: new google.maps.Place('ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4'),
        map: map
    });
}
```

This function is called after the map has loaded.

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", addPlaces);
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want to place a marker on the map at the place with the place_id: 'ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4', you need to make a [getDetails](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlacesService) request to the [PlaceService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details_requests)

```
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.getDetails({
    placeId: 'ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4'
}, function (result, status) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        place: {
            placeId: 'ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4',
            location: result.geometry.location
        }
    });
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/mt4kgxy2/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

code snippet:

```js
var map;
var infoWindow;
var service;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 19,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.257195, 3.716563)
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.getDetails({
    placeId: 'ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4'
  }, function(result, status) {
    if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      alert(status);
      return;
    }
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: result.geometry.location
    });
    var address = result.adr_address;
    var newAddr = address.split("</span>,");

    infoWindow.setContent(result.name + "<br>" + newAddr[0] + "<br>" + newAddr[1] + "<br>" + newAddr[2]);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=places&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```