# @react-google-maps make map open and center POI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, react-google-maps

I am using `@react-google-maps/api` with React 17.0.2 for a small project. I currently have a list of coordinates, and when I click various buttons, the map centers itself on a marker at one of those coordinates. However, a lot of the places I want to center on are "POI"s, and they already have built in markers and an info box with the correct name, address, and a link to google maps. (Seen [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9ssi.png)) Is it possible to make the map center on and open a specified POI? I have not found any documentation or examples of this. Simplified current code below:

```
const pinLocations = {
  location1: { lat: 1, lng: 1 },
  location2: { lat: 2, lng: 2 }
};

const Example = () => {
  const { isLoaded } = useJsApiLoader({
    googleMapsApiKey: API_KEY,
  });

  const [center, setCenter] = useState(pinLocations.location1);

  function updateMap(pinLocation) {
    setCenter(pinLocation);
  }

  return (
    <GoogleMap zoom={11} position={center}>
      <Marker position={center} />
    </GoogleMap>
      
    <Button onClick={() => updateMap(pinLocations.location1)}>
      Location 1
    </Button>
    <Button onClick={() => updateMap(pinLocations.location2)}>
      Location 2
    </Button>
  );  
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a stack snippet or a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? So that the community would be able to check your issue themselves and help you. :))

Comment: Since there isn’t a specific error or issue, would this still help? I’m more looking for documentation and/or whether or not this is possible with the current react-google-maps/api as opposed to a fully fleshed out solution.

Comment: Is what you're trying to look for is,  if it is possible to open your app then set the center automatically to a POI or marker with an info window showing its details? Is my understanding of your question right?

Comment: Pretty much, specifically a POI. Basically, is there a list of POIs somewhere? How do I open that built-in window that has all of the information without physically clicking on it?

Comment: After a bit more research, I've seen a couple implementations that use the `Places API` and `Directions API` to find POIs, but still nothing that lets me use a Place_ID to center and open the POI InfoWindow.

Comment: Have you seen this [Marker Example](https://react-google-maps-api-docs.netlify.app/#data:~:text=up%20the%20screen.-,Marker%20example,-Use%20%E2%8C%98%20%2B%20scroll%20to) from their docs? I think you can combine this with their [Info Window Example](https://react-google-maps-api-docs.netlify.app/#data:~:text=front%20of%20markers.-,InfoWindow%20example,-InfoWindow)

Comment: [Places API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#overview) enables your application to search for places (defined in this API as establishments, geographic locations, or prominent points of interest) contained within a defined area, such as the bounds of a map, or around a fixed point.

Comment: But you must take note that Place Search requests and Place Details requests do not return the same fields. Place Search requests return a subset of the fields that are returned by Place Details requests. If the field you want is not returned by Place Search, you can use Place Search to get a place_id, then use that Place ID to make a Place Details request. Using that Place Details request, you can get the coordinates(lat/lng) and the information about the POI you specify and use it for your `marker` and `infoWindow`.

Comment: The answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29723134/google-map-add-marker-using-place-id) question is what I meant in vanilla Javascript. I think it would be worth your time to study about how the Google Maps API works first.

Comment: Thanks for the time, but my goal was to **not** have to use the Places API or create my own custom `infoWindows`. The react-google-maps/api that I'm using automatically makes calls to the Places Details endpoint that you mentioned when you _manually_ click on a POI. I was wanting to "click" on a POI programatically. This may not be possible, and I probably just need to learn more about the API like you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It's possible. I was able to somehow replicate what the tactile map had through reverse geocoding with `@react-google-maps/api` library.**

**I did try to make it look like your sample above, and here's what I did:**

*I made a sample array of markers:*

```
    const markers = [
      {
        id: 1,
        position: { lat: 14.5432, lng: 121.0473 }
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        position: { lat: 14.5468, lng: 121.0543 }
      }
    ];
```

*Inside the `Map()` component, I made two hooks: One for the active marker, and also one for the infoWindow address result.*

```
const [activeMarker, setActiveMarker] = useState(null);
const [address, setAddress] = useState("Address");
```

*Then this is how I structured the `<GoogleMap>` component:*

```
return (
  <GoogleMap
    onLoad={handleOnLoad}
    onClick={() => setActiveMarker(null)}
    mapContainerStyle={{ width: "100vw", height: "100vh" }}
  >
  {/*maps the array of markers above*/}
  {markers.map(({ id, position }) => (
    <Marker
      key={id}
      position={position}
      onClick={() => handleActiveMarker(position, id)}
    >
      {/*show the infoWindow of the Active marker*/}
      {activeMarker === id ? (
        <InfoWindow
          onCloseClick={() => setActiveMarker(null)}
          options={{ maxWidth: 200 }}
        >
          <div>{address}</div>
        </InfoWindow>
      ) : null}
    </Marker>
  ))}
  </GoogleMap>
);
```

*The functions inside the `<GoogleMap>` are `handleOnLoad()`(for loading the map with bounds), and `handleActiveMarker`(for showing infoWindow and reverse geocoding the address inside the infoWindow).*

**#1**

```
//loads the map with bounds
const handleOnLoad = (map) => {
  const bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  markers.forEach(({ position }) => bounds.extend(position));
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
};
```

**#2**

```
//function for marker onClick
const handleActiveMarker = (position, id) => {
  if (id === activeMarker) {
    return;
  }
  console.log(id);
  /*this sets the current active marker 
  to help in what infoWindow to open*/
  setActiveMarker(id);
  // console.log(position);

  //start a geocoder here>>
  const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  // console.log(geocoder);
  geocoder
    .geocode({ location: position })
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.results[0]) {
        let fullAddress = response.results[0].formatted_address;
        //this changes the address default state on infoWindow
        setAddress(fullAddress);
      } else {
        window.alert("No results found");
      }
    })
    .catch((e) => window.alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + e));
    return;
};
```

I did not include a setCenter programmatically because I noticed the tactile map that you were referring to did not have one. It already automatically fits the infoWindow on the viewport.

Here's a codesandbox link if you need a reproducible example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-google-maps-api-multiple-markers-infowindow-forked-0zjogb?file=/src/Map.js

*note: Use your own API Key.*

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for all of the effort! I haven't worked on this part of my project in a while now, but came back to it today. Unfortunately this doesn't answer the part of my question about directly opening one of the existing POIs on the map, but this is a great work around!